# Calling @(Html.Kendo().Grid from within a jquery function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am displaying a kendo grid with razor asp.net mvc 4. I have a series of buttons, with each button displaying a different grid. Accordingly, I am using a jquery on click to pick up the button event. I am then just clearing the grid section of the dom, and reloading the new grid in its place. That is, I do not want to use href to reload the whole page as only wanting to load one section.

My question is, how do I call @(Html.Kendo().Grid from within a jQuery as it normally does not even sit in a script, and when put within, shows all syntax errors.

As you can see, I am not very proficient with the use of the models or functions, and if a function is the answer, where to put it. Any help would be appreciated.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if all you are trying to do is toggle back and forth between the two grids or if you are trying to get back to the server to grab updated data as well.

The first approach is simpler.  Let me know if this works for you:

Basically, write the code for both grids (so they both initialize at page load), but turn off the visibility for one.  Then, use jQuery to toggle the visibility of both grids on click.

**Jquery**

```
function toggleGridView(on, off) {
    var gridToShow = "#Grid" + on + "Container";
    var gridToHide = "#Grid" + off + "Container";
    $(gridToShow).show();
    $(gridToHide).hide();
}
```

**View Markup**

```
<a class="k-button" href="#_" onclick="toggleGridView('1', '2')">Show Grid 1</a>
<a class="k-button" href="#_" onclick="toggleGridView('2', '1')">Show Grid 2</a>

<div id="container">
<div id="Grid1Container">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UserModel.UserAddressBook)
        .Name("Grid1")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(i => i.CompanyName).Width(120).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "CompanyName" });
            //Other column data
        })
    )
</div>
<div id="Grid2Container" style="display:none;">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UserModel.UserProductBook)
        .Name("Grid1")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(i => i.Description).Width(120).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Description" });
            //Other column data
        })
    )    
</div>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for this answer and assistance, sorry didn't respond earlier, missed the response

Comment: No problem.  If it happens to work out for you, it'd be awesome if you could mark this as the answer.  Let me know if it's not (and why), and I can try again to help you out! :)